# How to convexify (relax) this L0 eigenvalue optimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $C_1,\dots,C_L$ be $N\times N$ hermitian matrices. Let $d<0$ be a given negative constant. Then consider the optimization problem
\begin{align}
\max_{r\in \mathcal{R}^{L\times 1}} &\mid\mid r\mid\mid_0 \\
\mbox{subject.to.} ~~~~~~&~~\lambda_{min}\left(\sum_{i}r_iC_i\right)\leq d \\
~&~~\sum_ir_i=1,~~r\geq 0
\end{align}

Comment: Interesting looking problem. What's the application? I hate to say it but I don't think you're going to get a satisfying answer here. It's not just the $\ell_0$ norm; it's the *upper* bound on the minimum eigenvalue.

Comment: So the constraint is on the minimum eigenvalue of the convex combination of matrices? Is there any intuition on what that constraint means? How do you deal with eigenvalue constraints within a math programming framework?

Comment: Actually, wonko, there's quite a bit of work out there on eigenvalue and singular value optimization. It's basically what *semidefinite programming* is all about. So, for instance, the minimum eigenvalue of a Hermitian matrix is known to be a concave function of its elements. Thus a *lower* bound on the minimum eigenvalue is a convex constraint. An *upper* bound, on the other hand, is not. So this problem, alas, cannot be expressed in a semidefinite programming framework, and I'm not seeing any decent way to convexify it.

Comment: Ah. I hadn't really thought of SDPs in terms of eigenvalues. Thx.

Comment: It is a problem related to admission control in sensor networks. $r_i$ in some sense dictates the contribution of $i^{th}$ sensor. Objective is to maximize number of sensors.